# Cordova InAppBrowser - How to hide URL and display close button? Android

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I tried using this works in the emulator but not in the app

```
    window.open(url, '_blank', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Close,enableViewportScale=yes,hardwareback=yes');
```

Is there a way out???